# amcharts change Mapchart lines' strokewidth

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to set `strokeWidth=2` of lines based on this condition:

```
(id === "london" && did === "vilnius") else set "strokeWidth=8".
```

I have a chart in [codepen](https://codepen.io/Anisha-Ramanuj/pen/mdoEgQV).

```
function selectOrigin(id) {
  debugger
  currentId = id;
  var dataItem = originSeries.getDataItemById(id);
  var dataContext = dataItem.dataContext;
  chart.zoomToGeoPoint(dataContext.zoomPoint, dataContext.zoomLevel, true);
  var destinations = dataContext.destinations;
  var lineSeriesData = [];
  var originLongitude = dataItem.get("longitude");
  var originLatitude = dataItem.get("latitude");

  am5.array.each(destinations, function (did) {
    var destinationDataItem = destinationSeries.getDataItemById(did);
    if (!destinationDataItem) {
      destinationDataItem = originSeries.getDataItemById(did);
    }
    var sw = (id === "london" && did === "vilnius") ? 2 : 8;
    lineSeriesData.push({
  
      geometry: {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: [
          [originLongitude, originLatitude],
          [
            destinationDataItem.get("longitude"),
            destinationDataItem.get("latitude")
          ]
        ]
      },
      strokeWidth: sw,
      stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeBackground"),
      strokeOpacity: 0.09
    });
 });
 
 lineSeries.data.setAll(lineSeriesData);
}
```